# Is there a way to get the line number with out a macro in c++?

Tags: c++, gcc

I am writing a logger and I would like the logger to also record which line, function, and file called it. I have tried `#define my_logger(format, ...) _log(format, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __VA_ARGS__)` which works however, this leads to several problems for me (I can't easily overload it, I can't put it in a namespace, not the most portable, etc).

Is there a way where I can declare a normal function like `void my_logger(const char* format, ...)` and in the function definition have it know the line it was called from with something equivilent to `__LINE_FUNCTION_WAS_CALLED_FROM__` if such macro existed? At a minimum it needs to work on GCC and really should be cross-platform.

Edit: By cross-platform, I only mean Linux and Windows on x86 and ARM

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/691719/10957435

Comment: @Chipster I don't want to use stack tracing because I want the logger to have then information even in release builds and I don't want the overhead of stack tracing

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't think that was exactly what you wanted, but I just figured I'd mention it since you should be able to accomplish the same thing that way if it was desirable. Of course, that way isn't portable across platforms anyway.

Comment: How many years of work can you afford spending on your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There cannot be such macro as `__LINE_FUNCTION_WAS_CALLED_FROM__`. There's no way it could work.

Since C++20, there is a way to get the line, function, etc. into a normal function by passing default initialised `std::source_location`:

```
void log(std::string_view message,
         std::source_location location = std::source_location::current());
```

However, since it relies on a defaulted parameter, variadic arguments are a bit tricky to implement: [How to use source_location in a variadic template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547273/how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function)

Prior to C++20, a macro is your only portable option.

---

I see that you call a function named `_log` in your macro. That identifier is reserved to the language implementation in the global namespace. You probably should give the function another name to avoid undefined behaviour.

`log` is also reserved in the global namespace. You should declare all your names in a custom namespace anyway (except that custom namespace naturally).

---

> [the macro is] ... not the most portable

If you were to replace `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` with `__func__`, then the macro would be portable to all standard conforming compilers - although the exact string given by `__func__` may differ between implementations.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem with _log. I'm coming from python where that's standard. Is there anything else I should avoid of that nature?

Comment: @EbonyAyers See the standard sections [lex.name] and [reserved.names]. By the way, `log` is also reserved in global namespace, so put it in a namespace of your own.

Comment: This can be implemented on your own with compiler builtins [How could `std::experimental::source_location` be implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34405913/995714)

Comment: @EbonyAyers [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/10957435) is a list of some things you shouldn't do with underscores.

Comment: I'm not seeing where `_log` specifically is reserved, but it does start with an underscore, so that would mean it's reserved for file scope, yes?

Comment: @Chipster Yes, it is reserved in the global namespace only.

Comment: @Chipster from 17.4.3.1.2 Global names [lib.global.names] "Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.165"

Comment: @eerorika: *"it cannot be used in conjunction with variadic arguments."*, see [how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547273/how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way where I can declare a normal function like void my_logger(const char* format, ...) and in the function definition have it know the line it was called from with something equivalent to `__LINE_FUNCTION_WAS_CALLED_FROM__` if such macro existed?

## Not in general.

On Linux x86-64, in 2020, with *all* your (or other) C++ code (C++11 or better) compiled with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information (so if using a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), with `g++ -g -Wall` and if using a recent [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), with `clang++ -g -Wall`), you might use Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) library.

Also, a good [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) is allowed to [inline expand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) or [unroll loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) (and actually `g++ -O2` or `clang++ -O2` will do both, and so does Microsoft compilers), and then your `__LINE_FUNCTION_WAS_CALLED_FROM__` makes no sense.

As an open source example, [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) is using it to show backtrace and part of call stacks. Disclaimer: RefPerSys is my own project.

Be aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) related to shared libraries. And plugins loaded with [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) add complexity to the picture.

> At a minimum it needs to work on GCC and really should be cross-platform.

It cannot be cross-platform. Some architectures (e.g. [IBM Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Z) series) have different [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), and you'll need efforts (or pay them) to port `libbacktrace` to them.

You might consider debugging on some systems, then porting your code to others, and you should consider using frameworks like [libSFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) for your game engine. My opinion is to recommend debugging your code on Linux (to make it correct) and later porting it to Windows.

If you need [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), things become harder. you may also consider [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) approaches: writing your C++ code generator or using other ones (e.g. like [SWIG](https://swig.org/) or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/))

Comment: As much as I love the Linux master race I am writing a game engine and unfortunately need to support windows. As part of that, I would like to support MSVC rather than locking windows builds to MinGW. I looked at stack tracing and would rather not use it as I would like to be able to have the logger track call locations even in build releases and I am not sure what performance penalty I would get from stack tracing.

Comment: My recommendation: compile on Linux (with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Once your code is debugged, port it to Windows. **First make your code correct and bug free on *one* computer and OS.** Later spend efforts on optimization and porting it to other platforms.