# How to disable copy elision for constructors with std::source_location?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, copy-elision, std-source-location

I am trying to add instrumentation to a widely used template class in my product. I am currently on `VS 2019 (16.10.4)` with `/std:c++17`. The new feature of [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) is a great addition for the kind of task I am interested in solving.  While [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) and [`std::experimental::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location) are  not available on my compiler, I built my own based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34406054/11057988). My goal is make changes to the class constructor/members in a special build and run tests. The changes to the class itself does not change its usage, so rest of the code remains same.

This all compiles and works great - mostly. **Except, I run into the [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) which almost beats the purpose of using `std::source_location`. I'd like my `source_location` to be the location at which the caller variable is defined instead of where the actual object is created.**

This problem can be demonstrated on `gcc -std=c++20` with and without `-fno-elide-constructors` as well. See simplified version of my minimal reproducible [godbolt sample](https://godbolt.org/z/nj6eYcrGr).

*MyClass:*

```cpp
class MyClass
{
private:
    int m_a = 0;
    std::source_location m_location;

public:
    MyClass(std::source_location location = std::source_location::current())
    : m_location(location)
    {
    }
    MyClass(const MyClass &other, std::source_location location = std::source_location::current())
    : m_a(other.m_a)
    , m_location(location)
    {
    }
    MyClass(MyClass &&other, std::source_location location = std::source_location::current())
    : m_a(other.m_a)
    , m_location(location)
    {
    }
};
```

*Usage:*

```cpp
MyClass getCopy1()
{
    MyClass ret;
    return ret;
}

MyClass getCopy2()
{
    return MyClass();
}

int main()
{
    MyClass o1;
    MyClass o2(o1);
    MyClass o3(getCopy1());
    MyClass o4(getCopy2());

    std::cout << "o1: " << o1.getLocationInfo() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "o2: " << o2.getLocationInfo() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "o3: " << o3.getLocationInfo() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "o4: " << o4.getLocationInfo() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

*Actual Output:*

```
o1: /app/example.cpp(56:13) int main()
o2: /app/example.cpp(57:18) int main()
o3: /app/example.cpp(46:12) MyClass getCopy1()
o4: /app/example.cpp(51:20) MyClass getCopy2()
```

*Expected Output:*

```
o1: /app/example.cpp(56:13) int main()
o2: /app/example.cpp(57:18) int main()
o3: /app/example.cpp(58:26) int main()
o4: /app/example.cpp(59:26) int main()
```

*Workaround 1 (explicit argument):*

```cpp
    MyClass o3(getCopy1(), std::source_location::current());
    MyClass o4(getCopy2(), std::source_location::current());
```

*Workaround 2 (`std::move`):*

```cpp
    MyClass o3(std::move(getCopy1()));
    MyClass o4(std::move(getCopy2()));
```

**While any of these workarounds above give me the results I desire, they are impractical. These will require me to change several instances of usage code and will beat the purpose of using something like [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location). Any changes to the `MyClass.h/cpp` that does not break its usage or any changes to the compiler flags is fair game. I intend to have a separate instrumented build that will not be used in production. My product  currently builds on `VS 2019 (16.10.4)` with `/std:c++17`.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55490839/4181011

Comment: C++17 changed the start of object lifetimes. It's no longer copy-elision, there simply aren't intermediate objects to be copied.

Comment: "Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to."

Comment: That's the thing -- it isn't an optimization. It's a change in *where execution happens*. If you're trying to use `source_location` for something other than identifying where execution happens, you should edit your question to clarify what specific feature you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The object `o3` in `main` is constructed in `getCopy1`, it is the same object as `ret`. Ditto `o4` and the un-named prvalue in `getCopy2`

Comment: @Sneftel Added and highlighted more details.

Comment: How about changing only `getCopy1` and `getCopy2` but not `o1...o4`?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That would be impractical too. Too many to modify. This is a template container.

Comment: You only need to change the type, not anything inside.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Not quire sure what you mean. Each instance of a function returning a `MyClass` object has its own logic. There are very many of these functions. Did your suggestion assume that `getCopy1()` constructs a clone of an existing object like so `getCopy1(o1)`? Maybe my function name is a misnomer. I should have named it `getObject1()/getObject2()`.

Comment: I mean that you only change the return type of each function without changing the logic. `MyClass` will take care of the mismatch.

Comment: That won't work here either, sorry. Too many of these.

Comment: Why do you need it to lie about `o3` and `o4` being constructed in `main`? There isn't a copy because the standard says there isn't a copy. That's how C++ works now, it is no longer an optimisation.

Comment: Good question @Caleth. I will update my post to include that info.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
template <int line, std::size_t N, basic_fixed_string<N> file> 
class MyClassImpl {
   public:
      // copy from any instantiation 
      template <int line2, std::size_t N2, basic_fixed_string<N2> file2>
      MyClassImpl(const MyClassImpl<line2, N2, file2>& other) { ... }
      // also move, assignment etc
      ...
};

#define MyClass MyClassImpl<__LINE__, sizeof(__FILE__)-1, __FILE__>
```

You can take `basic_fixed_string` from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r2.pdf) or roll your own; also feel free to use your implementation of `std::source_location` instead of the old-style macros if possible. The idea is to make each mention of `MyClass` a unique type. The template parameters are not used in the class definition, they could be anything, as long as they are unique.

Now there's no longer copy elision when you do

```
MyClass o3(getCopy1());
```

because the types are not the same, so there's no copy to be elided.

Of course this doesn't work at all if you use `auto`:

```
auto o3 = getCopy1(); // still has copy elision
```

so this is not a robust solution.